# Regex for matching season and episode

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm making small app for myself, and I want to find strings which match to a pattern but I could not find the right regular expression.

```
Stargate.SG-1.S01E08.iNT.DVDRip.XviD-LOCK.avi
```

That is expamle of string I have and I only want to know if it contains substring of S[NUMBER]E[NUMBER] with each number max 2 digits long.

Can you give me a clue?

Comment: Also, please tell us what program you're writing, if you open source it - there's a nifty program called theRenamer that does some of this similar work, but it's a very heavy program that isn't really standalone. - EDIT: Woops, TheRenamer has a command line mode too now.  Silly me! http://www.therenamer.com/

Comment: `/([Ss]?)([0-9]{1,2})([xXeE\.\-]?)([0-9]{1,2})/` - don't forget all those `1x04` style season/episode - numbers.

Comment: `([Ss]?)(\d{1,2})([xXeE\.\-])(\d{1,2})` (without the last `?`) is better, since the title can contain screen resolutions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Regex

[Here](http://regexr.com?31tqs) is the regex using named groups:

```
S(?<season>\d{1,2})E(?<episode>\d{1,2})
```

### Usage

Then, you can get **named groups** (season and episode) like this:

```
string sample = "Stargate.SG-1.S01E08.iNT.DVDRip.XviD-LOCK.avi";
Regex  regex  = new Regex(@"S(?<season>\d{1,2})E(?<episode>\d{1,2})");

Match match = regex.Match(sample);
if (match.Success)
{
    string season  = match.Groups["season"].Value;
    string episode = match.Groups["episode"].Value;
    Console.WriteLine("Season: " + season + ", Episode: " + episode);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("No match!");
}
```

### Explanation of the regex

```
S                // match 'S'
(                // start of a capture group
    ?<season>    // name of the capture group: season
    \d{1,2}      // match 1 to 2 digits
)                // end of the capture group
E                // match 'E'
(                // start of a capture group
    ?<episode>   // name of the capture group: episode
    \d{1,2}      // match 1 to 2 digits
)                // end of the capture group
```

Comment: Thank you :) this is exactly what i was looking for, using named groups is also very nice and useful

Comment: I want to do the same in IOS/Objective-c but itsn't getting any match with the same Regex and input string. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

There's a great online test site here: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Using that, here's the regex you'd want:

```
S\d\dE\d\d
```

You can do lots of fancy tricks beyond that though!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at some of the media software like XBMC they all have pretty robust regex filters for tv shows

See [here](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Adding_videos_to_the_library/Naming_files/TV_shows), [here](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Talk%3aUserdata/advancedsettings.xml)

Answer (score 0):

The regex I would put for S[NUMBER1]E[NUMBER2] is

```
S(\d\d?)E(\d\d?)       // (\d\d?) means one or two digit
```

You can get NUMBER1 by `<matchresult>.group(1)`, NUMBER2 by `<matchresult>.group(2)`.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to propose a little more complex regex. I don't have ". : - _"
because i replace them with space

```
str_replace(
        array('.', ':', '-', '_', '(', ')'), ' ',
```

This is the capture regex that splits title to title season and episode

```
(.*)\s(?:s?|se)(\d+)\s?(?:e|x|ep)\s?(\d+)
```

e.g. Da Vinci's Demons se02ep04 and variants
https://regex101.com/r/UKWzLr/3

The only case that i can't cover is to have interval between season and the number, because the letter s or se is becoming part if the title that does not work for me. Anyhow i haven't seen such a case, but still it is an issue.

Edit:
I managed to get around it with a second line

```
    $title = $matches[1];
    $title = preg_replace('/(\ss|\sse)$/i', '', $title);
```

This way i remove endings on ' s' and ' se' if name is part of series