# How to make regex that matches all possible episode numbers from a tv show file format?

Tags: regex

I would like to create a regex expression that matches all possible episode numbering formats from a tv show file format.

The related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12082536/regex-for-matching-season-and-episode), only matches in the following formats: S1E1, S11E1, S1E11, S11E11.

I would like to match the following formats: episode01, episode 01, episode1, episode 1, e01, e1, e0102, e01-02, e01e02, e01-e02, e111, e001002, e1-e2, e001-e002.

I currently have this regex which matches most but not all of the list of examples.

```
(?:(?<=e)|(?<=episode)|(?<=episode[\.\s]))(\d{1,2})|((?<=-)\d{1,2})
```

The one it does not match is when there are two episodes directly after another `e0102` should match `01` and `02`.

You can find the regex example with test cases [here](https://regex101.com/r/p02AQr/1)

Comment: In order to write a regular expression, you must first express in English what the rules are that you're trying to match. So what are the rules you want to use?

Comment: So you want to distinguish the 1st number from the optional 2nd number? If so, how would one distinguish `s01e0102` is episode `01` and `02` and not episode `0102`?

Comment: I think it's okay to assume episode lengths are less than 4, so I would like to match, multiple times, 1 or 2 digits until there are no more digit characters. So it would match `01`, then find `02` and match it - creating 2 matches. However, this approach would match `0`, `1`, `0`, `2`. I was wondering if there was a way of getting around this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per your comment, I went by following assumptions:

- Episode numbers are never more than three digits long;
- Episode strings will therefor have either 1-3 digits **or** 4 **or** 6 when its meant to be a range of episodes;
- There is never an integer of 5 digits assuming the same padding would be used for both numbers in a range of episodes;
- This would mean that lenght of either 4 **or** 6 digits needs to be split evenly.

Therefor, try the following:

```
e(?:pisode)?\s*(\d{1,3}(?!\d)|\d\d\d??)(?:-?e?(\d{1,3}))?(?!\d)
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/k9x53M/1) is an online demo. You'll notice I added some more samples to showecase the above assumptions.

---

- `e(?:pisode)?\s*` - Match either 'e' **or** 'episode' with 0+ trailing whitespace characters;
- `(\d{1,3}(?!\d)|\d\d\d??)` - A 1st capture group to catch 1-3 digits if not followed by any other digit **or** two digits;
- `(?:-?e?(\d{1,3}))?` - An optional non-capture group with a nested 2nd capture group looking for optional hyphen and literal 'e' with trailing digits (1-3);
- `(?!\d)` - There is no trailing digit left.